# ANTLR4: lexer rule for: Any string as long as it doesn't contain these two side-by-side characters?

Tags: antlr, grammar, antlr4, lexer, lexical-analysis

Is there any way to express this in ANTLR4:

> Any string as long as it doesn't contain the asterisk immediately
>   followed by a forward slash?

This doesn't work: `(~'*/')*` as ANTRL throws this error: `multi-character literals are not allowed in lexer sets: '*/'`

This works but isn't correct: `(~[*/])*` as it prohibits a string containing the individual character `*` or `/`.

Comment: Can you provide a little more details on what you are trying to achieve ? Must the string-without-*/ absolutely be recognized as a single lexer token ?

Comment: Hi Marc. Yes, a single lexer token: the lexer rule should return a single string as long as it doesn't contain */

Comment: There really should a simple way to do this in ANTLR.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The closest I can come is to put the test in the parser instead of the lexer.  That's not exactly what you're asking for, but it does work.

The trick is to use a semantic predicate before any string that must be tested for any Evil Characters.  The actual testing is done in Java.

```
grammar myTest;

@header
{
    import java.util.*;
}

@parser::members
{
    boolean hasEvilCharacters(String input)
    {
        if (input.contains("*/"))
        {
            return false;
        }
        else
        {
            return true;
        }
    }
}

// Mimics a very simple sentence, such as: 
//   I am clean.
//   I have evil char*/acters.
myTest
    : { hasEvilCharacters(_input.LT(1).getText()) }? String 
      (Space { hasEvilCharacters(_input.LT(1).getText()) }? String)* 
      Period EOF
    ;

String
    : ('A'..'Z' | 'a'..'z')+      
    ;

Space
    : ' '
    ;

Period
    : '.'
    ;
```

Tested with ANTLR 4.4 via the TestRig in ANTLRWorks 2 in NetBeans 8.0.1.

Comment: Thanks James! Wow, that is a huge amount of work to solve such a simple problem.

Comment: Can somebody explain how this works?  I don't see where it captures a token that contains a "*".  (I

Comment: Look in the parse method `hasEvilCharacters()`, which is called by the semantic predicate in the `myTest` parser rule.  For more info, read chapter 10 in The Definitive ANTLR 4 Reference.

Answer (score 6):

I had similar problem, my solution: `( ~'*' | ( '*'+ ~[/*]) )* '*'*`.

Comment: If you've coded more than one lexer for languages with /*....*/ comments, you should already know this trick.

Answer (score 1):

If the disallowed sequences are few there exists a solution without parser/lexer actions:

```
grammar NotParser;

program
    : (starslash | notstarslash)+
    ; 

notstarslash
    : NOT_STAR_SLASH
    ;

starslash
    : STAR_SLASH
    ;

STAR_SLASH
    : '*'+ '/'
    ;

NOT_STAR_SLASH
    : (F_NOT_STAR_SLASH | F_STAR_NOT_SLASH) +
    ;

fragment F_NOT_STAR_SLASH
    : ~('*'|'/')
    ;

fragment F_STAR_NOT_SLASH
    : '*'+ ~('*'|'/')
    | '*'+ EOF
    | '/'
    ;
```

The idea is to compose the token of

- all tokens that are neither '*' nor '/'
- all tokens that begin with '*' but are not followed with '/' or single '/'

There are some rules that deal with special situations (multiple '*' followed by '/', or trailing '*')

Comment: ... what happens with ANTLR if the last character in a file is an "*"?  What does the ~'/' test do or accept?

Comment: Should do now with the special cases (trailing '*', single '/', multiple '*'). Maybe the parse tree does not match the expectations ... but that is hard to tune without knowing the application.

Comment: The complexity and non-scalability of your answer and mine indicates a weakness--or is it an opportunity?--in ANTLR 4.